# How to compare php variable to value in a table?

Tags: mysql

My webpage is about an movie details .,It has a movie name which is passed into the variable  '$s' from database.

```
$s=$dis['moviename'];
```

Now i would like to check weather this movie name($s) is in 'album_name' column in the table 'galley_album'. If the movie name is there in the album_name in some xxx row , then i would like to echo all the column details like id ,name gallery_album of the movie.

so i used the below query for checking weather the movie is there in album_name or not .

```
$q = $db->query("select * from gallery_album where album_name like '$s'");   
while($qq=mysql_fetch_array($q)){

echo $qq['gallery_cat_id'];
  echo $qq['album_id'];
}
 ?>
```

How to echo the row details of the movie name if it is present in that column

Comment: WIthout knowing your table structure, we can't help you. Plus, I hope that `$s` is not something coming from a client-side form, otherwise your server is going to get totally [pwn3d](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: That's a plus, but you can still inject yourself.